# Error in building the DMTK Project ( MS Distributed machine learning toolkit)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fatal-error

I'm trying to setup and run the DMTK project on my pc, on visual studio 2013
I followed the setup steps one by one, now I'm getting a fatal error "can't open multiverso.lib" when building the solution
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should download and install DMTK Framework Binary first, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.dmtk.io/download.html.).

Click the "*Binary (Windows): x64*", not just "Source code", and you will find `multiverso.lib` in it. Then import it into your project.